# Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibria in Games of Imperfect Information

Tags: game-theory

For games of imperfect information (games with information sets), once you have found the pure and mixed strategy Nash Equilibria, how do you find the Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibria?

Comment: Via backward induction. Note that the set of Nash and Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibria differs only in sequential games (i.e., in simultaneous move games there is no need to look at SPNE).

Comment: Any SPNE is also NE. So you need to check whether NE that you found is also SPNE. That is, check whether at each subgame NE prescribes the optimal play.